# function does not exist

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(val NUMERIC)
RETURNS NUMERIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE in NUMERIC DEFAULT 0
    IF val=50000 THEN
        set in=1
    END IF
    RETURN in
END;


SELECT x.* FROM db_learn.public.individual_customer x
    JOIN (SELECT t.customer_rk, myfunc(t.monthly_income_amt) AS lwst FROM db_learn.public.individual_customer t 
    GROUP BY t.customer_rk HAVING myfunc(t.monthly_income_amt)=1) y
    ON y.customer_rk=x.customer_rk

LIMIT 50;
```

Ошибка : `function myfunc(numeric) does not exist` почему так?

Comment: `DELIMITER` Посмотрите документацию https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html на предмет ПРАВИЛЬНОГО синтаксиса. PS. А почему Вы проигнорировали сообщение об ошибке при попытке создания функции?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(val NUMERIC)
RETURNS NUMERIC
RETURN (val=50000)
END;
```

В такой версии DELIMITER не требуется.